# Write warning while typing in zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, zle

I know that it is possible to display text "outside" of the zsh prompt where you are typing. Common example is completions:

```
myhost Wed 8 10:06 ~/sandlot 
$ e .py█
```

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, et voilá:

```
myhost Wed 8 10:06 ~/sandlot 
$ e .py█
 -- file --
lenum.py           lexample.py        otherticks.py
```

What interests me is the text from `--file--` below. Is there some kind of "zsh_echo_below_zle" or something. I don't mind about about keyboard or shortcuts, since my intention is to *run* and use the output in zle. S.a.

```
myhost Wed 8 10:06 ~/sandlot 
$ some_command $(some_command_with_warning)█
```

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and

```
myhost Wed 8 10:06 ~/sandlot 
$ some_command some_output█
 -- warning: some_output is about yadda yadda yadada --
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the ZSH completion system, a custom message upon mashing of <kbd>tab</kbd> for a particular argument of a command is possible via the `_message` function, as shown in this completion script (`_foo`) for a particular command (`foo`):

```
#compdef foo

local curcontext="$curcontext" state

_arguments -C -s \
  '1: :->dofoo' \
  && return 0

case "$state" in
  dofoo)
    _message -r " -- warning: lp0 on fire"
    _values "parameters" $(_call_program getparam echo aaa bbb)
  ;;
esac
```

E.g.

```
% ls $fpath[*]/_foo 2>/dev/null
/Users/jdoe/.zsh/functions/_foo
% rm ~/.zcompdump && exec zsh
% function foo () { echo "$@" }
% foo █
 -- warning: lp0 on fire
aaa  bbb
```

(When modifying `$fpath` to include a custom directory, always do that *before* the `autoload -U compinit && compinit` commands.)

However, given a command line of `echo $(foo bar)█`, the completion `_foo` is *not* involved when <kbd>tab</kbd> is mashed, as this is a command substitution, and *not* an autocompletion of `foo`.

During command substitution, the command being substituted has no indication whether it is being run directly or as a command substitution (there is a special `ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT` variable though exporting that only indicates `toplevel` regardless), and [writing to the terminal then restoring the cursor position](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) will be complicated:

```
% cat awkward 
#!/bin/zsh
echo -ne "\e7\n -- warning: lp0 on fire\e[F\e8" >/dev/tty; echo blat
% ./awkward 
blat
% echo $(./awkward)
```

... though that's hardly perfect, as if the prompt is down at the bottom of the screen, horrible buggy things happen:

```
% echo -ne "\e[$LINES;0H"
...
% ./awkward 

blatwarning: lp0 on fire
% echo $(./awkward )
 -- warblat         fire
```

A more complicated program would need to deal properly with being at the bottom of the terminal, or even use `ncurses` for portability, and will need to somehow indicate to `zsh` that any custom line(s) written (may) need to be cleared so the display does not risk being mucked up with the output of a subsequent command. But that's more work.

The `zsh` code in `Src/exec.c` does not look like it does anything special for a `cmdsubst` job, and the `preexec` hook function is not called for command substitution, either. So I'm really not seeing anything simple for custom below-the-prompt terminal messaging during the execution of a command substitution in `zsh`.

Comment: well, the final objective is to press <kbd>tab</kbd> for autocompletion. I used the command output replacemente because I'm familiar with it and I believe that writing auto completer has a steep learning curve.

Comment: "Outlook's not so good". Ok, then... will have to meddle with the autocompletion system. Thx